# JavaFX и proGuard(обфускация)

Tags: java, javafx, proguard

Пытаюсь обфусцировать JavaFX приложение, но получаю такие ошибки и поэтому jar-ник не запускается. Как избавиться от ошибок и грамотно обфусцировать JavaFX код ? Если у кого есть рабочий пример конфига proGuar , поделитесь пожалуйста.
P.S. Работаю с proGuard первый раз. Все ответы на overflow прочитал по данной тематике, ответы не помогли решить проблему.
P.P.S. Jar файлы выбрал все , так как не знаю в каком находится JavaFX.

Файл конфигурации proGuard

```
-injars in.jar
-outjars out.jar

-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar

-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-flattenpackagehierarchy ''
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml,**.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @javafx.fxml.FXML *;
}

-keepclassmembernames class * {
       org.h2 *;
    }

-dontwarn "org.h2.**", "org.joda.time.**", "org.apache.**"

# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main'
# methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class com.javafx.main.Main, org.egogo.StartGraphicsHere {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keep class * implements java.sql.Driver
```

Ошибки.

```
ProGuard, version 5.2.1
Reading program jar [/home/konstantin/utils/proguard/proguard5.2.1/lib/in.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [netscape.javascript.JSException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [netscape.javascript.JSObject]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar]
Note: there were 2 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'org.h2'
Note: org.apache.log4j.jmx.Agent: can't find dynamically referenced class com.sun.jdmk.comm.HtmlAdapterServer
Note: org.apache.log4j.net.ZeroConfSupport: can't find dynamically referenced class javax.jmdns.JmDNS
Note: org.apache.log4j.net.ZeroConfSupport: can't find dynamically referenced class javax.jmdns.ServiceInfo
Note: org.apache.log4j.spi.LocationInfo: can't find dynamically referenced class com.ibm.uvm.tools.DebugSupport
Note: org.h2.message.TraceSystem calls '(org.h2.message.TraceWriter)Class.forName(variable).newInstance()'
Note: org.h2.store.fs.FilePath calls '(org.h2.store.fs.FilePath)Class.forName(variable).newInstance()'
Note: org.h2.util.SourceCompiler: can't find dynamically referenced class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
Note: org.h2.util.SourceCompiler$GroovyCompiler: can't find dynamically referenced class org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.ImportCustomizer
Note: org.h2.value.CompareMode: can't find dynamically referenced class com.ibm.icu.text.Collator
Note: org.joda.time.DateTimeZone calls '(org.joda.time.tz.Provider)Class.forName(variable).newInstance()'
Note: org.joda.time.DateTimeZone calls '(org.joda.time.tz.NameProvider)Class.forName(variable).newInstance()'
Note: org.apache.http.client.utils.JdkIdn accesses a method 'toUnicode(java.lang.String)' dynamically
      Maybe this is program method 'org.apache.http.client.utils.Idn { java.lang.String toUnicode(java.lang.String); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.apache.http.client.utils.JdkIdn { java.lang.String toUnicode(java.lang.String); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.apache.http.client.utils.Punycode { java.lang.String toUnicode(java.lang.String); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.apache.http.client.utils.Rfc3492Idn { java.lang.String toUnicode(java.lang.String); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'java.net.IDN { java.lang.String toUnicode(java.lang.String); }'
Note: org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpResponseProxy accesses a constructor '<init>(java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler)' dynamically
      Maybe this is library method 'java.lang.reflect.Proxy { Proxy(java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler); }'
Note: org.apache.log4j.jmx.Agent accesses a method 'start()' dynamically
      Maybe this is program method 'org.apache.commons.collections4.iterators.CollatingIterator { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationMonitor { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.apache.log4j.jmx.Agent { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.bnf.Sentence { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.command.Command { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.server.Service { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.server.TcpServer { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.server.pg.PgServer { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.server.web.WebServer { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.server.web.WebThread { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.tools.Server { org.h2.tools.Server start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.client.FlightRecordingClient { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.management.FlightRecordingMBean { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.applet2.Applet2 { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.panel.JreFindDialog$SearchPanel { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.ui.DialogHelper$3 { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.Applet2Adapter { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTGrayBoxPanel { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.FXApplet2Adapter { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.text.TextAppletAdapter { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.glass.ui.Timer { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2 { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.javafx.runtime.async.AbstractAsyncOperation { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.javafx.runtime.async.AsyncOperation { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextInputControlSkin$CaretBlinking { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PrismImageLoader2$AsyncImageLoader { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.jmx.snmp.daemon.CommunicatorServer { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.jmx.snmp.daemon.CommunicatorServerMBean { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.media.sound.DataPusher { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.media.sound.RealTimeSequencer { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.media.sound.SoftAudioPusher { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.media.sound.SoftMixingClip { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.media.sound.SoftMixingSourceDataLine { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.util.BCELFactory { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.util.BCELifier { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.scenario.animation.shared.ClipEnvelope { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'java.applet.Applet { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'java.lang.ProcessBuilder { java.lang.Process start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'java.lang.Thread { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'java.util.regex.MatchResult { int start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'java.util.regex.Matcher { int start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javafx.animation.AnimationTimer { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javafx.concurrent.Service { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javafx.scene.image.Image$Animation { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javafx.scene.image.Image$ImageTask { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javax.management.monitor.CounterMonitor { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javax.management.monitor.GaugeMonitor { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javax.management.monitor.Monitor { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javax.management.monitor.MonitorMBean { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javax.management.monitor.StringMonitor { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorServerMBean { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javax.management.timer.Timer { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javax.management.timer.TimerMBean { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javax.sound.midi.Sequencer { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javax.sound.sampled.DataLine { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javax.swing.Timer { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.regexp.JdkRegExp$DefaultMatcher { int start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.regexp.JoniRegExp$JoniMatcher { int start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'oracle.jrockit.jfr.FlightRecording { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.awt.X11.XScrollRepeater { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.font.LayoutPathImpl { double start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.font.LayoutPathImpl$EmptyPath { double start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.font.LayoutPathImpl$SegmentPath { double start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServerImpl { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.plugin.BeansApplet { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.plugin2.jvm.JVMLauncher { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.plugin2.jvm.ProcessLauncher { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.plugin2.jvm.ProxyJVMLauncher { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.plugin2.jvm.RemoteJVMLauncher { void start(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.plugin2.main.server.JVMInstance { void start(); }'
Note: org.h2.engine.FunctionAlias accesses a method 'isVarArgs()' dynamically
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.engine.FunctionAlias$JavaMethod { boolean isVarArgs(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleInfo { boolean isVarArgs(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'java.lang.reflect.Constructor { boolean isVarArgs(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'java.lang.reflect.Executable { boolean isVarArgs(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'java.lang.reflect.Method { boolean isVarArgs(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'java.lang.reflect.Parameter { boolean isVarArgs(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement { boolean isVarArgs(); }'
Note: org.h2.engine.SessionRemote accesses a method 'getInstance()' dynamically
      Maybe this is program method 'org.apache.commons.io.FileCleaner { org.apache.commons.io.FileCleaningTracker getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.apache.log4j.helpers.NullEnumeration { org.apache.log4j.helpers.NullEnumeration getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender { org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.engine.Engine { org.h2.engine.Engine getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.engine.UserAggregate { org.h2.api.Aggregate getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.expression.JavaAggregate { org.h2.api.Aggregate getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.store.RecoverTester { org.h2.store.RecoverTester getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.tools.CompressTool { org.h2.tools.CompressTool getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.tools.MultiDimension { org.h2.tools.MultiDimension getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.h2.util.TempFileDeleter { org.h2.util.TempFileDeleter getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.joda.time.DateTimeComparator { org.joda.time.DateTimeComparator getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.joda.time.chrono.BuddhistChronology { org.joda.time.chrono.BuddhistChronology getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.joda.time.chrono.CopticChronology { org.joda.time.chrono.CopticChronology getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.joda.time.chrono.EthiopicChronology { org.joda.time.chrono.EthiopicChronology getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.joda.time.chrono.GJChronology { org.joda.time.chrono.GJChronology getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.joda.time.chrono.GregorianChronology { org.joda.time.chrono.GregorianChronology getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology { org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.joda.time.chrono.IslamicChronology { org.joda.time.chrono.IslamicChronology getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.joda.time.chrono.JulianChronology { org.joda.time.chrono.JulianChronology getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.joda.time.convert.ConverterManager { org.joda.time.convert.ConverterManager getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.oracle.deploy.update.UpdateCheck { com.oracle.deploy.update.UpdateCheck getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.oracle.deploy.update.UpdateCheckFactory { com.oracle.deploy.update.UpdateCheck getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util { com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.config.Config { com.sun.deploy.config.Config getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.security.CredentialManager { com.sun.deploy.security.CredentialManager getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.security.SelectableSecurityManager { com.sun.deploy.security.SelectableSecurityManager getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.security.UnixCredentialManager { com.sun.deploy.security.CredentialManager getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.ui.ImageLoader { com.sun.deploy.ui.ImageLoader getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppContext { com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppContext getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTDragHelper { com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTDragHelper getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXAppContext { com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXAppContext getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.text.FXAppContext { com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.text.FXAppContext getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.util.BlackList { com.sun.deploy.util.BlackList getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.util.TrustedLibraries { com.sun.deploy.util.TrustedLibraries getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.deploy.xdg.BaseDir { com.sun.deploy.xdg.BaseDir getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.imageio.plugins.bmp.BMPMetadataFormat { javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadataFormat getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageMetadataFormat { javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadataFormat getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFStreamMetadataFormat { javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadataFormat getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageMetadataFormat { javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadataFormat getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGStreamMetadataFormat { javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadataFormat getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGMetadataFormat { javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadataFormat getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.imageio.plugins.wbmp.WBMPMetadataFormat { javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadataFormat getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager { com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.javafx.css.converters.BooleanConverter { javafx.css.StyleConverter getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.javafx.css.converters.ColorConverter { javafx.css.StyleConverter getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.javafx.css.converters.CursorConverter { javafx.css.StyleConverter getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.javafx.css.converters.DurationConverter { javafx.css.StyleConverter getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.javafx.css.converters.EffectConverter { javafx.css.StyleConverter getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.javafx.css.converters.EffectConverter$DropShadowConverter { com.sun.javafx.css.converters.EffectConverter$DropShadowConverter getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.javafx.css.converters.EffectConverter$InnerShadowConverter { com.sun.javafx.css.converters.EffectConverter$InnerShadowConverter getInstance(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.javafx.css.converters.FontConverter { javafx.css.StyleConverter getInstance(); }'
```

Ошибки при запуске out.jar

```
log4j:WARN No such property [conversionPattern] in au.A.
bs.l: (Message HY000 not found) [50000-187]
    at bv.a.b(DbException.java:345)
    at bv.a.a(DbException.java:168)
    at bv.a.a(DbException.java:295)
    at bo.u.c(SessionRemote.java:349)
    at bs.f.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:108)
    at bs.f.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:92)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.egogo.db.DataBaseConnectionPreState.<init>(DataBaseConnectionPreState.java:26)
    at org.egogo.StartGraphicsHere.start(StartGraphicsHere.java:75)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$50(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: bo.i.getInstance()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at bo.u.c(SessionRemote.java:344)
    ... 16 more
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.egogo.db.a.<init>(NewTables.java:19)
    at org.egogo.StartGraphicsHere.start(StartGraphicsHere.java:76)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$50(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как поступил я.
1.Стал собирать jar файл без сторонних библиотек. Библиотеки вынес в отдельную директорию.В gradle это выглядит так:

```
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:4.3.6"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0"
    compile "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1"
    compile "net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3"
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"
    compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.187'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.12'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.1'
}

jar {
    baseName = 'outputFileName'
//Помещаем сторонние библиотеки в наш jar-ник
//    version =  '0.1.1'
//    manifest.attributes("Main-Class": mainClassName);
//    from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }

//Создаем manifest и включаем в него класс для старта приложения и включаем путь(Classpath) до сторонних библиотек(зависимости), которые нам нужны.
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Main-Class": mainClassName,
                "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect {"libs/" + it.getName() }.join(' ')
        )
    }
}

//Копируем все зависимости в папкупроекта libs/
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'build/libs/libs'
}
```

2.Создаём файл конфигурации proGuard.У меня файл выглядит так:

```
-injars /home/konstantin/myProg.jar #jar файл который будем шифровать
-outjars /home/konstantin/myProgOut.jar #jar файл который получим после шифрования

#Обязательные библиотеки для JavaFX приложения(так они располагаются в Linux Mint)
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar

#Необходимые библиотеки(зависимости из gradle файла.Я их скопировал в отдельную папку для удобства)
-libraryjars /home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/fluent-hc-4.3.6.jar
-libraryjars /home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/httpclient-4.3.6.jar
-libraryjars /home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/commons-collections4-4.0.jar
-libraryjars /home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/jsoup-1.8.1.jar
-libraryjars /home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/opencsv-2.3.jar
-libraryjars /home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/commons-io-2.4.jar
-libraryjars /home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/h2-1.4.187.jar
-libraryjars /home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar
-libraryjars /home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/joda-time-2.1.jar
-libraryjars /home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
-libraryjars /home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/httpcore-4.3.3.jar
-libraryjars /home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/commons-codec-1.10.jar
-libraryjars /home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
-libraryjars /home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/log4j-1.2.17.jar

-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-flattenpackagehierarchy ''
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml,**.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

#Исключаем классы , в которых не должны обрабатываться методы, которые заканчиваются на Property()(к примеру nameProperty())
-keepclassmembers public class org.prog.javafx.** {
    public javafx.beans.property.StringProperty *Property();
    javafx.beans.property.** *Property();#Не изменять переменные данного типа(нужно чтобы в таблице(TableView или TreeTableView) отображались данные)
}

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @javafx.fxml.FXML *;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers public class com.javafx.main.Main, org.prog.StartGraphicsHere {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keep class * implements java.sql.Driver
```

Запускаем в консоли команду

> java -jar /home/konstantin/utils/proguard/proguard5.2.1/lib/proguard.jar @/home/konstantin/utils/proguard/proguard5.2.1/lib/applications.pro

Вывод консоли

```
~ $ java -jar /home/konstantin/utils/proguard/proguard5.2.1/lib/proguard.jar @/home/konstantin/utils/proguard/proguard5.2.1/lib/applications.pro
ProGuard, version 5.2.1
Reading program jar [/home/konstantin/myProg.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar]
Reading library jar [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar]
Reading library jar [/home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/fluent-hc-4.3.6.jar]
Reading library jar [/home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/httpclient-4.3.6.jar]
Reading library jar [/home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/commons-collections4-4.0.jar]
Reading library jar [/home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/jsoup-1.8.1.jar]
Reading library jar [/home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/opencsv-2.3.jar]
Reading library jar [/home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/commons-io-2.4.jar]
Reading library jar [/home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/h2-1.4.187.jar]
Reading library jar [/home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar]
Reading library jar [/home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/joda-time-2.1.jar]
Reading library jar [/home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar]
Reading library jar [/home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/httpcore-4.3.3.jar]
Reading library jar [/home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/commons-codec-1.10.jar]
Reading library jar [/home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar]
Reading library jar [/home/konstantin/Temp/CLASSES/log4j-1.2.17.jar]
Preparing output jar [/home/konstantin/myProgOut.jar]
  Copying resources from program jar [/home/konstantin/myProg.jar]
```

и на выходе получаем обфусцированный jar-файл с именем myProgOut.jar.

applications.pro - файл настроек proGuard. Может иметь любое имя и находится в любой папке, при запуске после @ укажите полный путь до файла.

Всем удачи!

P.S. Делаем задачу в gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        //Путь до /home/konstantin/utils/proguard/proguard5.2.1/lib/proguard.jar
        flatDir dirs: '/home/konstantin/utils/proguard/proguard5.2.1/lib'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ':proguard:'
    }
}

task proguard(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    //Имя нашего конфига proGuard, который мы создали.Файл нужно положить к корень проекта
    //Только из конфига нужно удалить строки
    //        -injars /home/konstantin/myProg.jar #jar файл который будем шифровать
    //        -outjars /home/konstantin/myProgOut.jar #jar файл который получим после шифрования
    configuration 'applications.pro'

    injars 'build/libs/myProg.jar'
    outjars 'build/libs/myProgOut.jar'
}
```