# Как защитить исходный код?

Tags: java, android

Нужно сделать так, чтоб apk файл нельзя было прочитать.

Как по мне достаточно стандартная ситуация, но все ссылки которые я нашел ведут сюда

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Но тут описано как сделать обфускацию и все такое, но мне нужно именно как то защитить код от приложений которые могут открывать apk файл и читать весь код

Если я правильно понял то это делается с помощью `pro-guard` файл , но не могу найти как

Подскажите кто сталкивался

Comment: Файл, который нельзя прочитать нельзя и запустить. Самый просто вариант решения вашей хотелки - удалить файл. Нет файла - нет чтения из него.

Comment: Обфускация и есть обработка кода с целью затруднить реверс-инжиниринг.

Comment: Выполнять код на сервере, а в приложении результат возвращать?

Comment: Ну, обфускация, наверное, и правда единственное решение для обфускации, это правда :]

Comment: pro-guard известный инструмент и поэтому есть инструменты, которые могут помочь бороться с ним. а зачем вам защитить файл? чем он так ценен?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman вот не знаю) получил такое задание, защитить файл чтоб его никто не мог прочитать

Comment: ну так стоит уточнить, что они имеют ввиду.

Comment: Не android, но Pro Guard https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452764/javafx-и-proguardобфускация

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DexProtector вам в помощь, стоит конечно 800$, но проверяли в действии. Отдавали реверсерам, никто так и не смог вытащить хотя бы отдаленно читабельные исходы

Comment: что с производительностью приложения в итоге?

Comment: все хорошо, но апк толстеет ощутимо (при всех активных методах защиты), у нас например потолстел на 500кб (было 800+, стало 1.3мб)

Comment: Оказалось, что защиты которую предлагает `Proguard` не достаточно. Хотел спросить, вы слышали что то о `DexGuard` я так понял это тоже самое что и `DexProtector` только от самого `Proguard` не могу понять как их сравить.... Что лучше что хуже?

Comment: @Aleksey достаточно сравнить функционал **dexguard** и **DexProtector**, и сразу увидите что лучше. Лично я за **DexProtector**

Comment: @Magic Действительно функционал у `DexProtector` намного шире. А в плане интеграции в проект я из комментариев понял, что никаких пролем нет?

Comment: @Aleksey нет, проблем нету,, хотите - встраивайте, хотите - обфусцируйте уже готовый апк

Answer (score 2):

DexProtector - хорошее платное решение, из бесплатных обфускация Proguard`ом, а вообще лучшее решение было в комментариях, выполнять все на сервере, а в приложении только показ результата.

Comment: Но ведь по сути proguard обфускация не делает ничего кроме того, что обрезает неиспользуемые части кода... Другими словами она вообще ничего не делает для защиты кода... или я не так понял?

Comment: Не совсем так, он переименовывает классы и члены классов, которые не являются точками входа. Точки входа сохраняют свое оригинальное название. Это затрудняет декомпиляцию и исследование работы приложения.
По Proguard'у советую почитать эту статейку(и продолжение если интересно): [Нажми на меня](http://jollydroid.ru/notebook/2016-12-29-ProGuard-1)

Comment: К сожалению не могу комментировать еще один ответ на данный вопрос, напишу его тут)
DexProtector еще сильнее усложняет задачу, но все равно можно реверснуть приложение, от этого ничего не спасет. Вам нужно определить что важнее время+800$ или исходный код.

Comment: декомпилировать то да, как делать нечего, а вот получить хотя бы читабельные исходы, чтоб хоть немного была понятна логика - вот это уже тяжело. + DexProtector не так давно обзавелся дополнительной функцией HideAccess

Comment: @Magic Cогласен, но мне трудно представить что надо так сильно(800$ + немало времени если человек с этим не знаком) прятать в android приложении и нельзя перенести на backend.

Comment: @Dast6Tino , вы хоть раз пользовались DexProtector'ом?) там даже дурачок поймет как юзать. Открыл gui - выбрал апк - выбрал нужные функции - нажал кнопочку - профит

Comment: Ну как сказать, у меня ушло немного больше времени)

Comment: Оказалось, что защиты которую предлагает `Proguard` не достаточно. Хотел спросить, вы слышали что то о `DexGuard` я так понял это тоже самое что и `DexProtector` только от самого `Proguard` не могу понять как их сравить.... Что лучше что хуже?

Comment: @Magic Оказалось, что защиты которую предлагает `Proguard` не достаточно. Хотел спросить, вы слышали что то о `DexGuard` я так понял это тоже самое что и `DexProtector` только от самого `Proguard` не могу понять как их сравить.... Что лучше что хуже?