# Есть ли защита от декомпиляции андроид-приложения?

Tags: android, apk, декомпиляция

Существует множество прогамм-декомпиляторов, которые моментально из апк создают папки с исходным джава-кодом. Но есть приложения, которые не декомпилируются,
значит защита есть.
Как можно реализовать защиту от декомпиляции андроид-приложения?
Нигде не дано нормального ответа!Только ссылки на общую документацию.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как защитить исходный код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711939/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Первое и самое главное что необходимо понять, говоря о защите программ,это то, что 100% защиты не существует. Как говорится, "если захотят и бронированные двери не помогут".

Можно использовать сторонние решения в виде, например, различных обфускаторов. Можно написать свою защиту, как, например, это сделал один из авторов на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/179487/). Но в любом случае, ничто не даст гарантии, что код Вашего приложения рано или поздно не восстановят.

Comment: Ну это хоть что-то. Спасибо.